# In Vulgate in Ecclesiastes 2:16, why does it say "et futura tempora oblivione *cuncta* pariter operient" (neuter accusative plural) and not "cunctos"?

Tags: adjective, vulgata

In Vulgate in Ecclesiastes 2:16, it says "*...et futura tempora oblivione **cuncta** pariter operient...*". I guess that's supposed to mean "*...and the future times will cover **entire them** by oblivion...*". However, why is "*cuncta*" neuter then, if it refers to people of unspecified gender? Shouldn't it be "*cunctos*", in masculine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuncta is neuter plural because it refers to “all things” rather than “all people.”